# PHP check for empty spots in ranges

Tags: php, php-5.3

Is it possible to spot empty ranges in an array with ranges, for example:

```
$ranges = array (
'1000-2000',
'2050-5000',
'5050-9990'
)
```

As an output it needs to be like:

```
$notInRanges = array (
'2001-2049',
'5001-5049'
);
```

The range is from 1000 till 9999. Too bad i can't get it done and can figure it out.

I did got the PHP code to fill an array with all filled items, and did get an array what isn't filled in range:

```
foreach ($ranges as $range) :
    $rangeParts = explode('-', $range);

    for($i=$range[0];$range[1] > $i;$++) :
        $rangeItems[] = $i;
    endfor;
endforeach;

for($i=1000;$i<=9999;$i++) :
    if (!in_array($i, $rangeItems)) :
        $notInRanges[] = $i;
    endif;
endfor;
```

But can't figure out how to make it an array like ['2001-2049'],['5001-5049'] or a way to do this.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, PHP does not actually have a function for *everything*. To achieve what you want, you'll actually need to write an algorithm that produces the output you want.

Comment: Do a range 1000-9999 then loop your $ranges with an array_diff.

You can't do it one shoot but, it's the way to begin.

Comment: The answer to the question is yes, but that's too short to submit.

Comment: @popnoodles what question? There's no question mark anywhere.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes "Is it possible to spot empty ranges in an array with ranges"

Comment: I did add the code i already have. But can't figure out how to create a range of it. (5001-5049)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah hell I was bored anyway:

```
define('MIN_RANGE', 1000);
define('MAX_RANGE', 10000);

$ranges = [
  '1000-2000',
  '2050-5000',
  '5050-9990'
];

$filled = [];
foreach($ranges as $range) {
  list($from, $to) = explode('-', $range);
  $filled = array_merge($filled, range($from, $to));
}
$filled = array_flip($filled);
$notInRange = [];
for($i = MIN_RANGE; $i < MAX_RANGE; $i++)
{
  if(!isset($filled[$i]))
  {
    $beginRange = $i;
    for($i = $i+1; $i <= MAX_RANGE; $i++)
    {
      if(isset($filled[$i]) || $i >= MAX_RANGE)
      {
        $notInRange[] = $beginRange.'-'.($i-1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
var_dump($notInRange);
```

Output as expected:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '2001-2049' (length=9)
  1 => string '5001-5049' (length=9)
  2 => string '9991-9999' (length=9)
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Now trying to figure out what it exacly does. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I just realized an optimization - modified it to be 2 lines shorter and functionally identical. Also, note that the algorithm is already optimal through the use of the nested `if` with the same variable, so this is also the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ranges = array (
    '1000-2000',
    '2050-5000',
    '5050-9990'
);

foreach($ranges as $k=>$range)
    if ($k>0)
        if ((int)substr($range, 0, strpos($range, '-')) <> (int)substr($ranges[$k-1], strpos($ranges[$k-1], '-')+1)+1)
            $gaps[] = ((int)substr($ranges[$k-1], strpos($ranges[$k-1], '-')+1)+1) . '-' . ((int)substr($range, 0, strpos($range, '-'))-1);

print_r($gaps);
```

Comment: This leaves 2000 and 5000 in the gaps and I would use explode instead of substr+strpos, but +1 because the rest of us are idiots for assuming we should use arrays instead of strings.

Comment: It's also not safe against overlaps, and as such imo not a complete solution.

Comment: Sorry, trivial fix. This will probably not be what he wants to use and I am not sure if he wants to return EVERY range between 1000-9999 that is not in the array or only starting at the first and ending at the last. 

Yes, it is not safe against overlaps, and it does work for the scenario given. However, the asker does not specify whether there will be overlaps in the ranges given.

Comment: Call me a purist but I tend to never trust any kind of input  :)  Either a solution is complete or a bug waiting to happen - and not taking overlaps into account here could be a highly mysterious bug in 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you a full code, but following should help you to get started

1. Sort the array
2. Use foreach to walk over the array and check if start-position is last end-position + 1, if not you found a gap

Comment: If we're not posting full answers: 1. Create a range of the min and max values. 2. Use array_diff

Comment: This will actually not work properly, consider `['1050-2000','1100-1150','1200-1250']`. Your code would show non-existent gaps.

Comment: He didn't say there was overlap ;) But indeed, the array_diff is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$ranges = array (
'1000-2000',
'2050-5000',
'5050-9990'
);
$extremes=range(1000,9990);

$existing=array();
foreach ($ranges as $range){
    list($min, $max)=explode('-', $range);
    $existing=array_merge($existing, range($min, $max));
}

$missing=array_diff($extremes, $existing);
//print_r($missing);

$missing_chunks=array();
$chunks=0;
foreach ($missing as $m){
    if (!isset($missing_chunks[$chunks])) $missing_chunks[$chunks]=array('max'=>$m);
    if ($missing_chunks[$chunks]['max']==$m-1) $missing_chunks[$chunks]['max']=$m;
    else {
        $chunks++;
        $missing_chunks[$chunks]=array('min'=>$m, 'max'=>$m);
    }
}

print_r($missing_chunks);
```

The result $missing_chunks isn't perfect and it's slow

Comment: Thanks for that, much more efficient as mine. But it gives all numbers and not the ['2001-2049'],['5001-5049'] what i can't figure out. But much more efficient as mine.

Comment: Just trying to do that bit as efficiently!